# Error Hosting web API in Blazor Server when launch as a service

Tags: c#, windows, blazor

I want to host a web API in my Blazor application, the problem is that the routes of this API can't be found when I use my application as a windows service, but they work correctly when I launch the application directly from the exe file..

Comment: Is there any doc you followed to turn blazor to windows service?

Comment: I'm using Advanced Installer. By the way everything else work perfectly except the API Routes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked by editing my controllers,
I changed this:

```
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Initialize]

    public class SocieteController : ControllerBase
    {
```

with this:

```
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

    public class SocieteController : ControllerBase
    {
```